# Number of overlapping frames generated by STFT

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

Im using `scipy.signal.stft` to get the stft of an audio. No porblem with that and I'm getting the results. But what I don't understand is, when an audio of `169600 samples` whose sample rate is `fs=44100 Hz` is used to calculate `stft`, I get 3 returns as `f, t` and `Zxx`. Here the shape of `Zxx` is `(2049, 84)`.

For calculating `stft` I use a window of size `4096`, and as the window type the `hanning window` is used. And by default, `scipy.signal.stft` uses a `window_size // 2` overlap between frames.

My question: Is there `2049` ovelapping frames? if so or if not, how to calculate the number of overlapping frames in stft? if `2049` is not the number of ovelapping samples, what does that number mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT of a real-valued signal yields a spectrum with Hermitian symmetry. That means that the upper half of the spectrum can be obtained from the lower half. Also, when the FFT size `N` is even, the mid point is its own symmetry. As a result the spectrum is fully determined by `N//2 + 1` frequency point (which is the size of spectrum returned by `scipy.signal.stft`). In your case `N` is `4096`, so you get a spectrum of `4096//2 + 1` or `2049` points along the frequency axis. You should be able to confirm that `f` is indeed an array of `2049` frequency values (from 0 to 44100/2 Hz in 44100/4096 or ~10.77Hz increments).

As far at the number of time values is concerned you can compute it as

```
number_of_samples = 169600
number_time_values = (number_of_samples+window_size)//(window_size - window_size//2) 
%  = (169600 + 4096)//(4096 - 2048) 
%  = 84
```

The `+window_size` (`+4096` in your case) term in the numerator is due to the `boundary = 'zeros'` default option which pads the input with zeros before and after your actual 169,600 input samples.

Comment: Oh well indeed.Thanks for your explanation. Now I understand what those numbers mean!